# Pivot and Group w/out Aggregation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table

```
Col A     Col B
===============
1            a
1            b
1            c
2            a
2            b
3            a
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Col A   Col B    Col C   Col D  
===============================
1       a         b         c
2       a         b
3       a
```

Of course this is highly simplified. I would like this for any N number of distinct variations of Column B values with any M number of distinct variations for column A values.

This is for MS-SQL 2014 if that helps.

Thank You for your time.

Comment: What do you do if there's several similar rows since you don't want aggregation?

Comment: I guess that's what I mean by grouping. I know how to do this if Column B was an integer using pivot. I would sum or count etc.. which is what I meant by aggregation.. sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: Search for dynamic pivot, there should be a lot of examples

Comment: with non integer fields just use min or max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use a pivot for this:

```
Select ColA
  , a AS [Col B]
  , b AS [Col C]
  , c AS [Col D]
 From have
 pivot
 ( max(ColB) for ColB in ([a], [b], [c])
 ) pvt
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c745/3)

or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query) for doing this dynamically.